# Beam Hardening in computed tomography

Tags: medical-physics

My question is, why in CT do they reduce the beam hardening effect with high KV?

The reason I am asking this is, that beam hardening is when say an x-ray passes through a patient and the low energy photons are absorbed by the patient and only high energy photos are left? But why would you reduce this effect if as then there would be no contrast effectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the detector/film is sensitive to all energies, and the image produced by it may assume a certain relationship between the density/path and the attenuation.

But this relationship is likely not valid for a beam with a wide spread of energies.  Instead, short paths attenuate much of the "soft" energies, while long paths may attenuate only some of the "hard", it won't be proportional.  This systematic difference in attenuation means the reconstructed image is prone to errors (usually increasing the brightness at the edges).

By hardening the beam before it reaches the sample, this effect is reduced.  Less of the easily attenuated "soft" energies reach the sample, so the difference in attenuation between short and long paths of the remaining beam is more easily determined.

If a monochromatic energy beam could be produced, this wouldn't be a problem.